# 2D Rectangular grid

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I tried solving the following problem at https://nus.kattis.com/problems/apples but my code does not pass the test cases. I'm new to C and I'm not particularly sure where I have gone wrong. My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int r,c;
    scanf("%d",&r);
    scanf("%d",&c);
    char arr[r][c];
    for (int i=0; i<r;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
            if(arr[i][j]=='a' && arr[i+1][j]=='.'){
                arr[i][j] = '.';
                arr[i+1][j] = 'a';
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
            printf("%c",arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

If I had to guess, I would put my finger on checking if arr[i][j] is equals to 'a' as the 'a' at arr[i][j] would be of different address from a generic 'a'.

Comment: You don't have any code to read in the initial apple positions; you're only running a single iteration of the gravity rule; and you have no handling for `#` obstacles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out, you are missing the initial grid reading code.
As it won't help you directly solve the problem, the code for reading the grid could help you advance.

As it is a 2d grid there is [two way of storing the data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order):

- row major (the way you did, and a natural way of organizing data), where the data is stored in a array of rows
- column major, where the data is stored in a array of columns

For the problem it would be more advantageous to store the data in a column major format. But for the sake of completeness I will provide you with both ways of storing

```
// Row major
char arr[r][c];
int count = 0;
int ch;
while (EOF != (ch = fgetc(fp))) {
    if(ch!='a' && ch != '#' && ch != '.') continue;
    row = count / c;
    col = count % c;
    arr[row][col] = ch;
}
```

```
// Col major
char arr[c][r];
int count = 0;
int ch;
while (EOF != (ch = fgetc(fp))) {
    if(ch!='a' && ch != '#' && ch != '.') continue;
    row = count / c;
    col = count % c;
    arr[col][row] = ch;
}
```

the reason I am recommending you column major storage, is the problem would be better solved if your treat each column separately.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not reading inputs (the contents of grid) properly. You must read from the standard input with scanf or other input functions before you check conditions and perform more tasks.

Although, if you declare `r * c` size of char array, push input to them and run the code, it'll check on the `r`th index on `arr[i+1][j]=='.'` part. You should avoid this by declaring array slightly bigger or by modifying your logic.